# C++ define macro /D with output of a shell command WINDOWS

Tags: c++, shell, visual-studio-2017, command, preprocessor

I am trying to define a macro that gets the output of a shell command, just like in Linux when using gcc and passing arguments like:
 `gcc ... -DSEED=$(date +%s)`
This is what I tried just for testing purposes:
`/DTEST=$(echo 5)`
Is it even possible to do something like this in vs2017 ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is in fact a bash/terminal question.

Comment: Why is it off-topic ? I wanted to know if it's possible to do something like this using visual studio. It's related to C++ macro definitions...

Answer (score 0):

Yes/No/Maybe/I don't know.

```
int main() { return RET; }
```

is a valid program compiled with

```
/DRET=0
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/LWW_oS)

Now you need to invoke your compiler in a way such that `0` is replaced by whatever value you want, but this is well outside the scope of C++.

What about bash for windows + CMake?